# DOMParser parseFromString removing nodes only when iterating resulting body childNodes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, electron

I am writing an electronjs app. I want to parse a string to DOM nodes and try to use DOMParser parseFromString for that. Here is the code:

```
let str = '<div id="customerList" style="display: none;"><ul></ul></div><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/customerList.js"></script>';
let nodes = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body.childNodes;
console.log(nodes);
```

This returns a NodeList with 2 elements, the expected div and scriptl, in it. If I add the following part in the code, the first element, the div, disappears from the NodeList:

```
let str = '<div id="customerList" style="display: none;"><ul></ul></div><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/customerList.js"></script>';
let nodes = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body.childNodes;
console.log(nodes);
for (let node of nodes) {
  contentDiv.appendChild(node);
}
```

The for loop is after the console.log and somehow alters the behavior of the code before. I can't seem to figure out, why the code behaves like it does though...Since I want to provide information about the first element in an ipcRenderer call, this is actually quite frustrating at the moment. Why does the code behave like it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node.appendChild()` moves a node to the new destination. That's why it disappears from your node list.

You can clone the node to avoid that like so:

```
let str = '<div id="customerList" style="display: none;"><ul></ul></div><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/customerList.js"></script>';
let nodes = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html').body.childNodes;
console.log(nodes);
for (let node of nodes) {
  contentDiv.appendChild(node.cloneNode());
}
```

This will append clones of all(!) nodes from the list and keep your `nodes` list as is.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: Ok, I suspected something like this was happening since both are added to the page. I still don't understand, why the logging is affected before appendChild() is called though. Since appendChild is called on all children of the body, shouldn't the log be empty instead of still containing the 2nd element?

Comment: That puzzles me too ;) Most probably because we remove items from the node list while we still iterate over it. We delete the node, the second node moves to the first position and the loop terminates because it 'finds' no second node anymore.

Comment: Apparently, logging is async. That's why it logs the object in its state when the function resolves. A trick is to log the object as string, i.e. with JSON.stringify()